# What are you allowed to do if you only have 1 card in hand, and no Canastas yet?

Tags: canasta

In a four player game, if a player has only one card left but his team does not have a canasta, can he pull a card from the stack and discard one, still leaving him a card in his hand?

If the card he pulls is playable may he play it and pull another card until he has a discard that he could not play?

Answer (score 3):

If the player cannot pick up the discard pile because he cannot meld the card on top, or it is frozen, then he *has* to pick up the top card of the draw stack, and just discard 1. He has no other choice.

He cannot play a card from his hand, unless playing that card would turn a 6-card meld into a 7-card Canasta, because he is not allowed to go out without a Canasta.

There is no rule that would allow him to play a card, and then draw another card. You only draw once per turn.